# Android service which runs in background even if user closes/kills the activity

Tags: android, service, background

I want to create a messaging application, which will run in the background with a network connection, even if the user closes the activity.

I have tried by creating Intent service and Started Service. These are working when the app is in the background but getting stopped after clearing the application from "recent applications".

Comment: You can use android's WorkManager. Here's the official Android WorkManager link:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics

Comment: Thanks Amit, WorkManager solved the problem.